# Working of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was watching  Richard Buckland Lecture on youtube where he showed how pointer works but i am having some problem here
according to him we use pointer because sometimes it may happen that we are not aware about the variable who contain the values 
For example

```
void main()
{
    int x=20,y=30;
    task(x,y)
    getch();
}
void task(int x,int y)
{}
```

so it will create two copies of in task() of variable x and y which are completely independent from the original one because task() is not aware about Original variables and so we use pointers so that  task() can get direct access to the main() variables x and y's address.

so if we say &x its refers to address on which value of x is located but if we say *x that's mean *20 that's something like the value located on the address 20 right? And its correct if we follow the concepts of Pointers in C.

But rather then returning the value located on address 20 it show me "invalid indirection" error.

**Its not that i am not aware about that error but  it is that why c compiler give me that error. I am still following the concepts of pointer but in different way. So i guess conceptually I am correct but still syntactically I am wrong. Why?**

Comment: Why we study assembly language, example #31417.

Comment: i guess to program using mnemonic. So do you mean its about machine code.@egrunin

Comment: What makes you think you own address 20?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: if you spend two days learning the basics of assembly language, it will save you two *years* of such confused questioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *20 that's something like the value located on the address 20 right?

Right, more or less, *but*:

- It's really the value *beginning* at address `20`. In order for the compiler to know the size of the value, and the type of the expression, it has to know what type of value you mean, so you have to *cast* `20` to the appropriate pointer type. For example, `(int*)20` is a pointer-to-`int`, so `*((int*)20)` has type `int`.
- You can't safely just "make up" an address like this, because it's unlikely that you have actually been allocated a memory-block that includes address `20`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you mean (your English is insupportably poor!), but if I understand it correctly, you want to dereference a constant address specified as an integer like this:

```
int someVar = *20;
```

Now the type of `20` is int, which is not a pointer type, so it cannot be dereferenced. You have to convert it to a pointer of an appropriate type for that:

```
int someVar = *(int *)20;
```

And yes, this will most likely segfault.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to understand is that C does not have a concept of "pass by reference" like C++ does. That means that the compiler creates a copy of any variables you pass regardless the type of the variable. Where the copy is saved depends on the compiler, the architecture, optimization level, etc. In general you don't have neither to worry nor to know where it saved. What really matters is that in a function you get a copy.

In theory you may access any address of the memory by doing something like this:

```
int *var = ((int*) 0xdeadbeef);
*var = 3;
```

meaning: Cast the values `0xdeadbeef` into an integer pointer and save it in `var`. Then save the value 3 in the block (on x86 4 bytes long) starting at `0xdeadbeef`. While this is correct C you surely will get a segfault, because today's operating systems use the memory controller to give you access to a limited set of addresses/blocks.

When you do this:

```
int var = 10;
```

the compiler will store the value 10 somewhere (it might be stored in a register, but let's assume that the compiler stores it in the RAM). As a C programmer you usually are not going to care where it is, the linker deals with the correct address.

Let's take a look at this piece of code

```
void foo(int f)
{
   /* do something with f */
}

void bar(int g)
{
    int f1 = 2;
    f1 += g;
    foo(f);
}
```

how is the compiler going to translate it into assembler? It may look like this

```
foo:
0xa0000000: load in register 1 the 4-byte value @ 0x12abcd00
0xa0000004: /* do something with register 1 */
0xa0000008: /* do something else with register 1 */
...
bar:
0xa0000c00: load in register 3 the 4-byte value @ 0x12ad0004
0xa0000c04: load in register 4 the value 2
0xa0000c08: add register 3, register 4 (result saved in 'result register')
0xa0000c0b: save the content of 'result register' @ 0x12abcd00 (look at the first line)
0xa0000c10: jump 0xa0000000  (call foo)
```

The same applies with pointers. Pointers are more or less an integer variable. They value that is stored by a pointer is an address. The difference to integers is that you can access (=dereference) the value stored at that address. And you do this by using the `*` operator (see first example `*var = 3`). The `&` operator returns the address of variable.

So when you have

```
void foo(int *x)
{
    *x = 3;
}

void bar(void)
{
    int i = 9;
    int *i_ptr = &i;
    foo(i_ptr);
    /* i is 3 */
}
```

C creates a copy of `i_ptr`, but the stored value of the copy if `i_ptr` still is the same as the address of `i`, hence `foo` can dereference it and modify the value of `i` even though `i` was not defined in `foo`.

So, when do we use pointers in C? In general these are the most common cases when you use pointers:

- we want to modify a variable we didn't declared in our function

  - e.g. we need to return more than 1 value at a time
- we use dynamic allocated memory (see `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`)
- we work with string

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're trying to say is this:

```
void task(int *px, int *py)
{
    /* get the addresses of two integers */

    *px += 10; /* change the value of the integer px is pointing to */
    *py += 20; /* change the value of the integer py is pointing to */
}

void main()
{
    /* make a space on the stack for two integers, assign values */
    int x=20;
    int y=30; 

    /* display those values */
    printf("x=%d, y=%d", x, y);

    /* pass the address of each value to a function */
    task(&x,&y);

    /* display the changed values*/
    printf("x=%d, y=%d", x, y);

    getch();
}
```

Because this passes the *addresses* of x and y, the function task() can change their values.